# Need some help on a somewhat complex LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have this query that does what I want which is to return true if any of the materials is comparable in the material groups list.

```
mgroup.MaterialGroups.Select(x => x.Materials
                                   .Any(m => Convert.ToBoolean(m.Comparable)))
                                   .Any(x => x.Equals(true))
```

What I would like to add to this query is to also include this one.

```
mgroup.Materials.Any(m => Convert.ToBoolean(m.Comparable));
```

How can I combine mgroup and it's materialgroups together in the query so I can select both of their Materials? Thanks.

**EDIT** - After fighting with LINQ for awhile I broke down and just combined as

```
mgroup.Materials.Any(m => Convert.ToBoolean(m.Comparable) || 
mgroup.MaterialGroups.Select(x => x.Materials
                     .Any(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.Comparable)))                                                                                                                                   
                     .Any(x => x.Equals(true)))
```

It works as expected but it's horribly long and it's embedded in an Asp.net MVC view to makes things even worse. If anyone can simplify this that would be amazing.

P.S.- If you are wondering why I added the extra .Any(x => x.Equals(true) at the end it's because without it the query returns an IEnumerable of bools instead of bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Material> allMaterials = 
                      mgroup.Materials.Concat(
                      mgroup.MaterialGroups.SelectMany(group => group.Materials));
bool result = allMaterials.Any(m => Convert.ToBoolean(m.Comparable));
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly that only returns true if an mgroup.MaterialGroup has a comparable material but doesn't return true if an mgroup itself has a comparable material. The second query I posted only works for the latter and the first one I posted only works for the former. That's why I am trying to combine them into one statement if possible.

Comment: Yep, it does indeed work. That's not a trivial query is it? Or maybe I just don't LINQ enough. lol In your opinion, which would be better to use in a View? Is it bad to declare an IEnumerable just to use for a condition?

Comment: @Smith Do you find the code block readable? If so, then it's perfectly legitimate to write it that way

Comment: Yea, it's definitely readable aside from the selectmany but I'll look that up. Thanks.

Comment: @Smith SelectMany concats the individual Material collections into 1 single Material collection